# Replacing text with Regex

Tags: javascript, python, regex

how can I replace the following text in python/javascript

```
Latency=45.466<span class="interval"> ± 11.462</span>;pass
```

in a way that it can show final text like this:

```
Latency=45.466±11.462;pass
```

Comment: What regex have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5754656

But seriously, try using a HTML parser first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to remove the `html` tags, for that, you can use:

```
import re
subject = 'Latency=45.466<span class="interval"> ± 11.462</span>;pass'
result = re.sub("<[^>]+>| ", "", subject)
print result
# Latency=45.466±11.462;pass
```

[Python Demo](https://ideone.com/aCiTqe)

---

For JavaScript you can use:

```js
subject = 'Latency=45.466<span class="interval"> ± 11.462</span>;pass'
result = subject.replace(/<[^>]+>| /g, "");
console.log(result);
```